# How to attach sensor from gazebo database(.sdf) to urdf model?

Tags: gazebo, urdf, sdf, ros-kinetic, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, In gazebo, there are already available models (insert tab) which you can simple insert in your scene. I am having trouble with using it with my urdf model.

I want to add velodyne to my robot. But the problem is that i cannot do this as the model available is in .sdf format. I have tried adding it using this link information http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=add_laser     but NO LUCK.

- -- -- I have also tried this approach but i cannot add velodyne using this approach though i have added different sensors using the same underlying concept: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins

I am using kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282369/how-to-attach-sensor-from-gazebo-database(.sdf)-to-urdf-model?/) by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the [velodyne_description](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_description) package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1